# Find cPanel username and passwords via FTP?

Tags: ftp, web-hosting, cpanel

I have adopted a site where no one knows the cPanel details or who is actually hosting it. The only way I can interact with the server is via FTP.

I know its a long shot but does anyone know a way I can retrieve/reset the cpanel credentials via FTP? Thanks

Comment: Your best solution here is to use http://whois.net/ to find out who is hosting the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your cPanel username/password are the same as your primary FTP username/password (unless you're logging in via a secondary FTP user created via cPanel).

So if your FTP host is www.mywebsite.com, then just go to http://www.mywebsite.com:2082 and try to login with your FTP credentials. It is highly unlikely that your cPanel service is host on a different server than your FTP service.

But to answer your question, no it is not possible to reset or retrieve your cPanel credentials via FTP.

To find out who is hosting the account, you can perform a whois on your domain name ( http://www.whois.sc/YOURDOMAINNAMEHERE.COM ) and take a look at the nameservers. The nameservers (unless they've been anonymously branded) will generally indicate which company you're hosted by.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I thought it woudnt be possible...unfortuneatly the cpanel or FTP details were changed at some point so theyre different from each other. Think my best bit is tracking down the host like you suggest